# is there any way of capture a flow of actions with chrome and export to selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, firefox, automation

I want to know if is possible to capture a lot of actions like a flow and export to selenium, in order to repeat that flow.

For example, I need to uninstall and reinstall and configure a few applications each day several times, the process is always the same, and it's a long process, so in order to avoid navigate between code to capture all IDs and classes, is there any way of doing that?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Selenium IDE](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/) is basically what you are looking for. It is a Chrome or Firefox extension that has a record and play back feature, and it is able to export working code in a variety of languages (including python).

Word of caution: tests produced by the tool tend to be pretty unreliable/flaky, you can attain much better stability by coding with WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

Using pyautogui or something similar you could record the location of each click and either use the color of certain pixels to intiate different stages or waiting x amount of time before click each saved point on screen

Comment: To me, this method sounds prohibitively flaky and unstable. Almost any change to the page under test would cause a false failure here.

Comment: Can you use selenium to install or uninstall or configure programs ? I thought selenium was just for the web?

Comment: I read the question such that all the actions the user wants to capture *are* in the browser ~"Capture a flow of actions with Chrome". But yes, Selenium can only automate the browser so if the asker is indeed wanting to automate outside the browser something like pyautogui would be needed.